# What will be faster: do action in one thread or in 40?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have done load testing with 1 thread and with 40 threads. As a result I got that  action (example inserting data into database) is faster in 1 thread then in 40. Does it good or in 40 threads this action need to be faster

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do

Comment: @TheLostMind can you give example in which situation doing in one thread is faster?

Comment: Inserting data means transactions. It's faster to complete one transaction with 40 inserts than 40 transactions with 1 insert. And in general, don't try to parallelize database insertion.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik There is a separate transaction for each insert

Comment: What @MarkoTopolnik says applies to other IO operations as well. CPU intensive operations perform better if multiple threads are used.

Comment: But it looks like 40 users are doing the same action or 1 user is doing

Comment: If you had 40 connections to 40 databases, that would be parallelization. If you have 40 connections to one database, that's just contention.

Comment: @Viktoriia - Well, if you have no control over how inserts happen (users concurrently calling insert api), then using one transaction per user request is correct. If you have to do 40 inserts, then you could batch them up and insert in one transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the action. 
For example if you are searching an single arraylist you don't need 40 but if you want parallel processing on multiple arrays you can use multiple threads